# SwiftUI UIViewRepresentable VideoPlayer updateUiView function causes infinite loop

Tags: swiftui, avfoundation, observableobject, uiviewrepresentable

I'm trying to implement a custom video player by using `UIViewRepresentable`.
I have the following implementation:

```
class PlayerUIView: UIView {

var videoName: String

private let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer()
private var playerLooper: AVPlayerLooper?
private var player: AVQueuePlayer?
private var placeholderImageView: UIImageView?

init(videoName: String) {
    self.videoName = videoName

    super.init(frame: .zero)
    setupPlayer()
}

@available(*, unavailable)
required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

func setupPlayer() {
    player = AVQueuePlayer()
    playerLayer.player = player
    playerLayer.masksToBounds = true
    playerLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
    playerLayer.contentsGravity = .resizeAspectFill
    layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)

    guard let player = player else { return }
    playerLayer.frame = bounds
}

func playVideo() {
    guard !videoName.isEmpty, let fileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: videoName, withExtension: "mp4") else {
        return
    }
    let asset = AVAsset(url: fileURL)
    let item = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)

    guard let player = player else { return }
    playerLooper = AVPlayerLooper(player: player, templateItem: item)
    player.play()
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    playerLayer.frame = bounds
}
}


struct PlayerView: UIViewRepresentable {

@State private var internalVideoTitle: String?

func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<PlayerView>) {
    print("UPDATE")
    guard let player = uiView as? PlayerUIView else { return }
    if internalVideoTitle != videoTitle {
        internalVideoTitle = videoTitle
        player.videoName = videoTitle
        player.playVideo()
    }
}

func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
    print("INIT")
    let player = PlayerUIView(videoName: videoTitle)
    internalVideoTitle = videoTitle
    return player
}
}
```

This is the view where I implemented the VideoPlayer

```
struct WarmupFlowView: View {

private enum NavigationDirection {
    case next
    case previous
}

@EnvironmentObject var workoutRouter: WorkoutRouter
@ObservedObject var workoutFlowVM: WorkoutFlowViewModel
@StateObject var workoutTimerVM = WorkoutTimerViewModel()
@State private var showInfoView = false
@State private var closeButtonTapped = false

var body: some View {
    LoadingView(isShowing: $workoutFlowVM.warmupFlowVM.state, message: "Warmup wird geladen...") {
        GeometryReader { reader in
            ZStack {
                VStack {
                    PlayerView(videoTitle: workoutFlowVM.warmupFlowVM.videoBinding ?? .constant(""))
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .top)
                        .frame(height: reader.size.height * 0.9)
                        .ignoresSafeArea()
                        .overlay(
                            ZStack {
                                WorkoutCloseButton(closeAction: closeAction)
                                infoButton
                            }
                                .padding(.top, 16)
                        )
                    Spacer()
                }
                VStack {
                    Spacer()
                        .frame(height: reader.size.height * 0.55)
                    if !workoutTimerVM.prepareLabelIsHidden {
                        Text("Test")
                            .customFont(.title4)
                            .foregroundColor(Color.text.opacity(0.8))
                            .padding(.bottom, 24)
                    }
                    WorkoutTimer(workoutTimerVM: workoutTimerVM,
                                 timeToPrepare: 7,
                                 secondsTotal: 30)
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)

                    Text(workoutFlowVM.warmupFlowVM.currentExercise?.title ?? "")
                        .customFont(.title2)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.text.opacity(0.8))
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        .lineLimit(2)
                        .padding(.top, 32)
                    Spacer()
                    HStack {
                        navigationButton(direction: .previous, disabled: !workoutFlowVM.warmupFlowVM.hasPreviousExercise())
                        Spacer()
                        navigationButton(direction: .next, disabled: !workoutFlowVM.warmupFlowVM.hasNextExercise())
                    }
                    WarmupProgressView(exercisesCount: workoutFlowVM.warmupFlowVM.exercises.count, actualIndex: workoutFlowVM.warmupFlowVM.getCurrentExerciseIndex())
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                        .padding(.bottom, 32)
                }
            }
        }

    }
    .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showInfoView, content: {
        if let videoTitle = workoutFlowVM.warmupFlowVM.currentExercise?.videoTitle, !videoTitle.isEmpty {
            ExerciseDetailInfoView(videoTitle: workoutFlowVM.warmupFlowVM.videoBinding ?? .constant(""))
        }
    })
    .navigationBarHidden(true)
    .onAppear {
        workoutFlowVM.warmupFlowVM.getWarmupExercises(for: [.all, .lowerBody])
    }
}

}
```

These are the `WorkoutFlowViewModel` and the `WarmupFlowViewModel`

```
final class WorkoutFlowViewModel: ObservableObject {

@Published var workout: Workout
@Published var warmupFlowVM: WarmupFlowViewModel

private var cancellable: AnyCancellable?

init(workout: Workout, warmupFlowVM: WarmupFlowViewModel) {
    self.workout = workout
    self.warmupFlowVM = warmupFlowVM

    cancellable = warmupFlowVM.objectWillChange.sink { [weak self] _ in
        print("WILL CHANGE")
        self?.objectWillChange.send()
    }
}

}

final class WarmupFlowViewModel: ObservableObject {

@Published var warmupExerciseRepo: WarmupExerciseRepositoryProtocol
@Published var state: LoadingState = .success
@Published var exercises = [WarmupExercise]()
@Published var currentExercise: WarmupExercise?
@Published var videoBinding: Binding<String>?

private let warmupCreator = WarmupCreator()
private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

init(warmupExerciseRepo: WarmupExerciseRepositoryProtocol = WarmupExerciseRepository()) {
    self.warmupExerciseRepo = warmupExerciseRepo
}

func getWarmupExercises(for areas: [ExerciseMuscleArea]) {
    state = .loading
    warmupExerciseRepo.getWarmupExercises(for: areas)
        .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
        .sink { [weak self] completion in
            switch completion {
            case .failure(let error):
                self?.state = .failed(message: error.description)
            case .finished:
                break
            }
        } receiveValue: { [weak self] warmupExercises in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            self.exercises = self.warmupCreator.createWarmupWorkout(exercises: warmupExercises)
            self.currentExercise = self.exercises[safe: 0]
            self.triggerVideoBinding()
            self.state = .success
        }
        .store(in: &cancellables)
}

private func triggerVideoBinding() {
    self.videoBinding = Binding<String>(
        get: { self.currentExercise?.videoTitle ?? "" },
        set: { newValue in
            self.currentExercise?.videoTitle = newValue
        })
}

}
```

Sorry for that much code. I tried to only bring in the revelant stuff.
My problem is the part with the `fullscreenCover`:

```
    .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showInfoView, content: {
        if let videoTitle = workoutFlowVM.warmupFlowVM.currentExercise?.videoTitle, !videoTitle.isEmpty {
            ExerciseDetailInfoView(videoTitle: workoutFlowVM.warmupFlowVM.videoBinding ?? .constant(""))
        }
    })
```

When I do this, the `updateUiView` function of the `PlayerView` is called infinite times.
I don't understand why because the `PlayerView` in the `WarmupFlowView` is called with the same data and there is no problem about it. Does the `fullScreenCover` modifier affect the `updateUiView` somehow?
When I use a NavigationStack and show the `ExerciseDetailInfoView` there. It also works perfect.
Btw this is the `ExerciseDetailInfoView`

```
struct ExerciseDetailInfoView: View {
@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

@Binding var videoTitle: String

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        PlayerView(videoTitle: $videoTitle)
            .ignoresSafeArea()
            .overlay(
                WorkoutCloseButton(closeAction: closeAction)
            )
    }
    .navigationBarHidden(true)
}

private func closeAction() {
    presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
}
}
```

I would appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 0):

The infinite loop issue is caused by the FullScreenCover modifier in the WarmupFlowView. When you present the ExerciseDetailInfoView, it creates a new PlayerView with a new Binding to the videoTitle. This leads to an infinite loop because SwiftUI keeps trying to update the PlayerView as it detects a change in the videoTitle.

Here's how you can modify the PlayerView:

```
struct PlayerView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var videoTitle: String?

    @State private var internalVideoTitle: String?

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<PlayerView>) {
        print("UPDATE")
        guard let player = uiView as? PlayerUIView else { return }

        if internalVideoTitle != videoTitle {
            internalVideoTitle = videoTitle
            player.videoName = videoTitle ?? ""
            player.playVideo()
        }
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        print("INIT")
        let player = PlayerUIView(videoName: videoTitle ?? "")
        internalVideoTitle = videoTitle // Initialize internal state with the initial value
        return player
    }
}
```

and modify triggerVideoBinding to this:

```
private func triggerVideoBinding() {
    self.videoBinding = Binding<String>(
        get: { self.currentExercise?.videoTitle ?? "" },
        set: { newValue in
            self.currentExercise?.videoTitle = newValue
        })
}
```

Remember to make corresponding changes in the ExerciseDetailInfoView where you use videoTitle as @Binding instead of @Binding<String?>.

With these modifications, the PlayerView should work correctly and avoid the infinite loop when presenting the ExerciseDetailInfoView.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! Unfortunately this does not solve the problem at all. I updated my question with the edited code. Now I also get the error "Modifying state during view update, this will cause undefined behavior." in the `updateUIView` function because I modify the `internalVideoTitle`. I get the same error for the `internalVideoTitle` modification in `makeUIView`. Do you maybe have any other idea?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow,  Hing Tat Tsang!

Many of your answers appear likely to be entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). Please be aware that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. 

We do hope you'll stick around and be a valuable part of our community by posting *your own* quality content. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In update, you're setting the internalVideoTitle `@State`, which will cause update to be called again, because update is called when any `@State` or `let` changes. Change it to this:

```
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: PlayerUIView, context: Context) {
        print("updateUIView")

        if uiView.videoTitle != internalVideoTitle{
            uiView.videoName = internalVideoTitle
            uiView.playVideo()
        }
    }
```